# How to create filter annotations display

Tags: objective-c, filter, annotations, mkmapview, uiswitch

I would like to create filter annotations display at my Map View . Example: 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hScpE.jpg)

where do I start?may be use UİSwitch button? Give me please tutorial. **Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know useful tutorial for you question, but i try to help you to create this view.
I think a good logic it's create `UITableView` with custom cells. `UITableViewCell` in your case contains **top label** (describing filter) and `UICollectionView`. `UICollectionViewCell` contains 3 `UIView` :

1. Just white `UIView`.
2. UIImageView - subview of first view. This image is a checkmark, for example. Center of `UIImageView` = **center** of first view.
3. Just a `UILabel` with description.

You have to observe delegate methods of collection view and set image or set 'nil' to `UIImageView` when didSelectMethods call. 
I hope that I give you a start point. If no, ask me, I try to help you.

Comment: I do not understand.can u explain in more detail?